# How to highlight the current item in an android listview?

Tags: android, listview

I know in touch mode there is no selected item. But I am trying to develop an android watch app which acts as a controller to an app in mobile. The mobile app has a list view and the watch app acts as a controller to scroll, select etc.

So I want the user to know the current selection and also when he/she performs the scroll in watch, the selection must scroll accordingly. How can I implement this?

Currently I am using message api to send messages to the mobile and by this I am able to control the scroll of the listview in mobile. Now I need to add the highlighter part.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily select a listview item by call the method setSelecttion(int position)

```
yourListview.setSelection(yourPosition);
```